# How to find $\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} \frac{{\overline z}^2-{\overline z_0}^2}{z-z_0}$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers

Fairly simple question, I want to find this limit

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{{\overline z}^2-{\overline {z_0}}^2}{z-z_0}$$

The original question was to find the region at which the function $f(z)=\overline z^2$ is differentiable, and if possible find $f'(z)$.

If $z=x+iy$, then from Cauchy-Riemann we get that $f$ is differentiable on the straight line $4ix+4y=0$.

Assume $z_0$ is on that straight line. $f'(z_0)$ is defined as $\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} \dfrac{{\overline z}^2-{\overline z_0}^2}{z-z_0}$ and I'm having problems finding that limit.

Of course that $\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} \dfrac{{\overline z}^2-{\overline z_0}^2}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} \dfrac{({\overline z}-{\overline z_0})(\overline z + \overline z_0)}{z-z_0}$ but that does not seem to help a great deal.

Comment: Note that $4ix + 4y = 0$ does not describe a line. Recall that $x$ and $y$ are both real.

Comment: You are correct ofcourse. $y,x$ are real, so no value of $x,y$ can give us this result. So it's not differentiable anywhere. so the limit is not supposed to exist. only at $0$.

Comment: So really, the limit we want to solve is $\frac{\overline z^2}{z}$ as $z$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Yes, and that is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final paragraph *does* help. Since $\bar z+\overline{z_0}\to 2\overline{z_0}$, we need to look at $\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{\bar z-\overline{z_0}}{z-z_0}$ (provided $z_0\ne 0$). But $\frac{\bar z-\overline{z_0}}{z-z_0}$ is just an arbitrary nonzero number divided by its conjugate, hence an arbitrary element of $S^1$ and the limit does not exist. (You might check what happens if $z=z_0+\epsilon \cdot e^{it}$).